# Socket.io - как организовать приложение

Tags: node.js, socket.io

никак не могу придумать хороший вариант как бы организовать приложение с использованием библиотеки socket.io.

В файле app.js я как положено создаю сервер, подключаю к нему сокет и получаю переменную io, которая мне как бы и нужна для того чтоб отправлять туда-сюда сокеты.

Но отправлять сокеты мне нужно не только из файлы app.js, но и из других. И как быть? Прокинуть io в качестве параметра функции?
Кажется, это плохая идея.

Я еще думал создать отдельный модуль, который бы занимался сокетами, а все остальные модули обращались бы к нему и передавали в него параметры, которые нужно отправлять. Ну это же совсем отлично, но проблема в принципе остается та же - io определено в файле app.js, модуль который я создам для работы с сокетами назовем socket.js.

Как мне быть с io? Создать его в app.js и передать в socket.js?
Создание io еще же связано с созданием сервера.
Вот этот момент совсем непонятен.

Comment: Сокеты никуда не отправляются, отправляются данные.

Comment: Спасибо, я это и имел ввиду, но выразился не так. Есть какая-то информация по поводу сути моего вопроса?